# Showing object private properties

Tags: php, class, private

This is homework. I have created 2 classes, Objecte and Ordinador. It is mandatory that Ordinador properties are private, and $preu in Objecte too.

```
<?php
class Objecte
{
var $model;
private $preu;

public function __construct($model,$preu)
{   
    $this->model=$model;
    $this->preu=$preu;  
}
}
?>
```

This is Ordinador:

```
<?php
include('classe_objecte.php');
class Ordinador extends Objecte
{
private $disc_dur;
private $ram;

public function Ordinador($model,$preu,$disc_dur,$ram)
{
    parent::__construct($model,$preu);
    $this->disc_dur=$disc_dur;
    $this->ram=$ram;    
}   
}
?>
```

So I have stored some objects I've created. They're stored in a SESSION array. So now I must show the values, but as they're private in the classes, I get this errors:

```
Notice: Undefined property: Ordinador::$preu 
Fatal error: Cannot access private property Ordinador::$disc_dur
```

Any suggestions how to access to it?.

Comment: You could add some getter methods to your classes; methods that return the values.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a public function that calls to the private var

```
public function getPreu(){
    return $this->preu;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yair, as I'm kind of newbie to PHP, how do I call that method from outside the class?

Comment: $obj = new Objecte('modele','preu');   And then echo $obj->getPreu();

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
parent::__construct($model,$preu);
```

try:

```
$this->__construct($model,$preu);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I'm storing the objects like this:

```
    $index=$_SESSION['numOrdinadorsO'];     
    $_SESSION['objetos_ordinador'][$index]=inserirOrdinadorO();
```

And funtion inserirOrdinadorO looks like this:

```
function inserirOrdinadorO()
{
    $_SESSION['ordinadorsO']=array('model_ordinadors'=>$_POST['model_ordinadors'],'preu_ordinadors'=>$_POST['preu_ordinadors'],'tamany'=>$_POST['tamany'],'ram'=>$_POST['ram']);

    $model=$_SESSION['ordinadorsO']['model_ordinadors'];
    $preu=$_SESSION['ordinadorsO']['preu_ordinadors'];
    $disc_dur=$_SESSION['ordinadorsO']['tamany'];
    $ram=$_SESSION['ordinadorsO']['ram'];

    $ord_tmp = new Ordinador($model,$preu,$disc_dur,$ram);

    $_SESSION['numOrdinadorsO']+=1;
    echo "Objecte Ordinador inserit.</br>";     
    return $ord_tmp;
}
```

Not sure how to implement the solution Yair gave me:

> $obj = new Objecte('modele','preu'); And then echo $obj->getPreu();